# Automated Load/Stress testing via a continuous integration server

Tags: load-testing, stress-testing, teamcity, jmeter

My company currently has stress tests that are run manually through JMeter. We also use TeamCity for automation of JUnit testing.

It's become clear that we need to automate our stress testing as well to provide more generalized testing of our entire web application. I have been looking for a solution where I could use JMeter within TeamCity but I have no yet found anything. Has anyone done this successfully? Anyone have other recommendations that I should consider?

Thanks,

Casey

**Update May 15th**

After some more research I have found some interesting scripts, particularly [jmeter-ec2](http://www.http503.com/2012/run-jmeter-on-amazon-ec2-cloud/#example). The ec2 API is a little criptic, but I could see the following working from within TeamCity:

1. Create ec2 AMI with latest version of our software on it.
2. Launch AMI as a virtual instance
3. Wait for server to come online
4. Run jmeter-ec2 against server with jmeter test set
5. Use jmeter-ec2 to retrieve test results
6. Parse test results and report back to TeamCity

This seems to reach the desired result but it also seems pretty complex. Anyone done this before or something like it who could comment on best practices?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether Cloud solution would be acceptable for you but there is a company which is offering Jmeter as a Service - ie basically SaaS solution. They claim that they have rich scripting capabilities so it might be one of the options for you.

http://aws.amazon.com/customerapps/3299

http://blazemeter.com/

I never used their services myself though but I'm aware of it as a possible solution. Also it's free to start with up to 10 tests.

[update] BlazeMeter now has a TeamCity plugin:
http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/155889-blazemeter-plugin-for-teamcity-jetbrains-

Comment: Thanks. This is pretty cool but I think we will want something that we can integrate a little more tightly with our CI server. Perhaps this can do that but I didn't see anything to indicate it on their website.

Comment: I see that they do have a REST API. Interesting...

Answer (score 0):

This [blog](http://samueladesoga.wordpress.com) shows someone:

- Running Jmeter with Ant
- Graphing the results
- Displaying the graph image in TeamCity (well, just suggesting you could)

http://samueladesoga.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/performance-testing-experience-using-ant-and-jmeter-part-2/

Further information

- [Display the result](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/Including+Third-Party+Reports+in+the+Build+Results) (embed any html)
- [Test results of JMeter test can not fail teamcity build configuration](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-21578) is an outstanding feature request

I have not tried it but it might help.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, looking for a solution to well know challenge of integrating performance testing with continuous integration process/server. There is a new open source project, which tries to address integration between JMeter and CI servers:

https://github.com/automatictester/lightning

Check wiki for information on how this tool integrates with CI servers in general, and TeamCity in particular. There are a few usage examples included as well. Feature requests are welcome.